# 1.7.10 Crashing upon entering Multiplayer (no forge, normal mc)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

when I try to join a Minecraft server running on 1.7.10, it just crashes when I join it. I'm trying to join invadedlands. The IP is right, but it crashes me after "Logging in..."

Crash log:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// My bad.

Time: 6/24/19 10:22 AM
Description: Ticking screen

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:540)
    at java.nio.DirectIntBufferU.get(DirectIntBufferU.java:253)
    at bma.a(SourceFile:271)
    at bma.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bao.a(SourceFile:1694)
    at bao.a(SourceFile:1652)
    at bjb.a(SourceFile:125)
    at hd.a(SourceFile:70)
    at hd.a(SourceFile:13)
    at ej.a(SourceFile:174)
    at bcx.e(SourceFile:78)
    at bao.p(SourceFile:1343)
    at bao.ak(SourceFile:774)
    at bao.f(SourceFile:728)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:540)
    at java.nio.DirectIntBufferU.get(DirectIntBufferU.java:253)
    at bma.a(SourceFile:271)
    at bma.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bao.a(SourceFile:1694)
    at bao.a(SourceFile:1652)
    at bjb.a(SourceFile:125)
    at hd.a(SourceFile:70)
    at hd.a(SourceFile:13)
    at ej.a(SourceFile:174)
    at bcx.e(SourceFile:78)

-- Affected screen --
Details:
    Screen name: bcx

-- Affected level --
Details:
    Level name: MpServer
    All players: 0 total; []
    Chunk stats: MultiplayerChunkCache: 0, 0
    Level seed: 0
    Level generator: ID 00 - default, ver 1. Features enabled: false
    Level generator options: 
    Level spawn location: World: (8,64,8), Chunk: (at 8,4,8 in 0,0; contains blocks 0,0,0 to 15,255,15), Region: (0,0; contains chunks 0,0 to 31,31, blocks 0,0,0 to 511,255,511)
    Level time: 0 game time, 0 day time
    Level dimension: 0
    Level storage version: 0x00000 - Unknown?
    Level weather: Rain time: 0 (now: false), thunder time: 0 (now: false)
    Level game mode: Game mode: survival (ID 0). Hardcore: false. Cheats: false
    Forced entities: 0 total; []
    Retry entities: 0 total; []
    Server brand: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Server type: Non-integrated multiplayer server
Stacktrace:
    at bjf.a(SourceFile:289)
    at bao.b(SourceFile:1972)
    at bao.f(SourceFile:737)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.7.10
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_51, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 104190592 bytes (99 MB) / 167772160 bytes (160 MB) up to 2147483648 bytes (2048 MB)
    JVM Flags: 8 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx2G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.7.10
    LWJGL: 2.9.1
    OpenGL: GeForce GTX 1060/PCIe/SSE2 GL version 4.6.0 NVIDIA 388.16, NVIDIA Corporation
    GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing.
Using framebuffer objects because OpenGL 3.0 is supported and separate blending is supported.
Anisotropic filtering is supported and maximum anisotropy is 16.
Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported.

    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: [vanilla]
    Current Language: English (US)
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Anisotropic Filtering: Off (1)
```

Comment: Did you use a new .minecraft folder?

Comment: Nope. The original .minecraft folder.

Comment: It shows there are 0 total players on the server. Are you sure that the server is configured correctly?

Comment: @Whitcheef Then do that. Downgrading within the same `.minecraft` folder is not officially supported and often causes crashes, even though they sadly usually don't say that.